# How to make join force to use index?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have a huge dataset on two tables (`users`, `pos_transactions`), and I need to execute a `join` on them.

I wrote the query both with `join` and *subquery* approches. Both looks Non-optimal:

```
explain SELECT pt.card_number
        FROM pos_transactions pt
        where user_id in (select id from users where belongs_to = "ezpay")
```

[image]

```
explain SELECT pt.card_number
        FROM pos_transactions pt
        join users u on u.id = pt.user_id
        where u.belongs_to = "ezpay"
```

[image]

See? In both cases over 2M rows will be scanned. Noted that I have these two indexes:

```
- `users(belongs_to)`
- `pos_transactions(user_id)`
```

Also, I have tried `force index()` for both indexes on both queries, but still it does full scan. Any idea how can I get the result in an optimal way?

Comment: Is id a primary key on users  table ?

Comment: Yes it is @ErgestBasha

Comment: It got about 2X better @ysth https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTZSF.png

Comment: Do users.id and pos_transaction.user_id have the same type (int, bigint)? Sometimes conversion from one type to the other results in not using the index.

Comment: @MartinAJ that's probably about as good as it will get; moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

1. you do not write properly your query because string must not use double quote but single quote. Double quote is reserved for SQL identifiers like COLUMN's name...
2. to use and index for a big table, you must have all the columns used by the table, not aonly the seeked ones...

Do you have the following indexes :

```
X001 ON pos_transactions (user_id, card_number)
X002 ON users (belongs_to, id)
```

?

Comment: Backtics are used for column names.  Double quotes can be used only in a certain, rarely used, mode.  So, that is probably not an issue.  (Meanwhile, the suggested ihndexes seem optimal.)

Comment: @Rick_James. No "backtics" does not exists in the standard SQL Language. It is a stupid thing comming from MySQL and now in MariaDB... Double quote won't be an issue until someone add a column in one of the tables that are in the query and the query will deliver false answer... So it is also a stupid thing to do !

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, it seems to think it shouldn't start with reading users, and that's going to get you the best plan possible (unless your query is going to end up selecting a large percentage of users and/or pos_transactions rows).  You can force it with straight_join:

```
select straight_join pt.card_number
from users u
join pos_transactions pt on u.id = pt.user_id
where u.belongs_to = "ezpay"
```

The only possible further improvement would be having a (user_id,card_number)  covering index on pos_transactions, but that's not likely to make a huge difference.